# Matching user code with database and redirecting winners / losers

Tags: php, mysql, user-input, matching

I am new to...well everything. Bear with me.

I have a website that has a textbox for user input ( a code they receive). When they submit, it sends the code to a PHP file, which then checks the code against a database. If it matches the winner code, it redirects the user to a specific page. Losers, are redirected to a loser page.

That works!

However, I'm now trying to redirect users to a third page, if their code matches a different table of codes, but I can't figure out the if else statements. Can anyone help a poor doodle like myself? Thanks!

Here's what I got:

```
// Connect to your MySQL database
$dbhst = "localhost";
$dbnme = "blah"; 
$bdusr = "blaaah";
$dbpws = "blahblahblacksheep";

// Using PDO to connect

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhst.';dbname='.$dbnme, $bdusr, $dbpws);

// Getting variables
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
$questionID = $_POST['questionID'];

// Comparing answers

try {

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Winners WHERE Winners='" . $answer . "' LIMIT 0,1");
  $stmt->execute();

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if ( count($result) ) {
      foreach($result as $row) { 
          // echo 'Congrats, you've entered a correct code';
          header("Location: https://get-a-brik.myshopify.com/pages/8522");
      }
  } else {
      // echo 'Your code did not win. Please try again.';
      header("Location: https://get-a-brik.myshopify.com/pages/5551");
      exit;
  }
  
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: This isn't how to use prepare()

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if ... else if ... else` statement:

```php
if (... user is winner ...) {

  header("Location: https://get-a-brik.myshopify.com/pages/8522");

} else if (... user is looser ...) {

  header("Location: https://get-a-brik.myshopify.com/pages/5551");

} else {

  header("Location: winner page");

}
```